# GMail API Users.threads.list Missing "Messages" Field

Tags: javascript, api, gmail-api

I'm able to use GMail's **Users.threads.list** API call to retrieve a list of the threads. I'd like to also grab the **labels** belonging to each message in the thread.

On the [official documentation / live example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list?authuser=1#php) for this method, there is an area called `fields` where the user can specify the optional fields they wish to pull in. They even provide a little UI tool call 'fields editor' to help you select and properly format the fields for inclusion in the REST query:

[image]

Which results in the following, *valid*, generated `fields` parameter values:

> nextPageToken,resultSizeEstimate,threads(historyId,id,messages/labelIds)

The final request looks like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?includeSpamTrash=true&fields=nextPageToken%2CresultSizeEstimate%2Cthreads&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

After authenticating with OAuth2, I get back a list of `threads[]`, but *none* of them include the expected `messages[]` array nested within them! I know the field mask is valid because GMail API errors out when you request a field the method doesn't support with a standard HTTP 400 and a pretty printed error message. But in this case, all I get back is an object that contains an array labeled "threads", where each thread object only has the following fields:

- id
- snippet
- historyId

But no messages array. Stranger yet, even when I remove the `fields` custom filter parameter, I still get back these same results. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [list the id of the threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list?authuser=1#try-it) first, and then make a separate request to [get the thread and fields in the messages you want](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get?authuser=1#try-it). The API Explorer allows you to select additional fields when listing for some reason.

### 1. List ids

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?access_token={access_token}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "threads": [
  {
   "id": "1570f8c16a1084de",
   "snippet": "Foo bar...",
   "historyId": "1234"
  }, ...
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 100
}
```

### 2. Get the thread

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/1570f8c16a1084de?access_token={access_token}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "1570f8c16a1084de",
 "historyId": "1234",
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1570f8c16a1084de",
   "threadId": "1570f8c16a1084de",
   "labelIds": [
    "INBOX",
    "IMPORTANT",
    "CATEGORY_FORUMS"
    ], ...
   }
  }
```

If you don't want to list threads and then get them all separately, you could use [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) to bring it down to 2 requests instead.