# Gmail API "Fields Mask" editor

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

Where is the `field mask` editor for making requests to Gmail API? is it removed? I found some questions related to this but seems the UI is not there anymore:

1. [Google API Explorer: Where is the "fields" parameter editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205359/google-api-explorer-where-is-the-fields-parameter-editor)
2. [GMail API Users.threads.list Missing "Messages" Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438717/gmail-api-users-threads-list-missing-messages-field)

I need to make a partial response that only return `subject` on the `headers` and the first body data on `parts`. With request format=full

Does anyone know where to find the UI editor or how to do this?
thank you!